# How to allow all IP traffic to activate

Tags: networking, internet-explorer, windows-server-2003, webclient

Windows Server 2003 Ent x64

(I know it's no longer supported but we have to fix some application bug before it can be upgraded to a new platform because of certification requirements)

Fresh install of server with AD and IIS (AD & Application roles)
Installed IE 8

The server can connect to the internet and ping and nslookup successfully.

nslookup:

> Microsoft Windows [Version 5.2.3790] (C) Copyright 1985-2003 Microsoft
>   Corp.
>
> C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>nslookup microsoft.com
>
> Server: google-public-dns-a.google.com Address:  8.8.8.8
>
> Non-authoritative answer: Name:    microsoft.com Addresses: 
>   23.100.122.175, 23.96.52.53, 191.239.213.197, 104.40.211.35
>             104.43.195.251

I need to activate the server online and
I need to allow a logged in user to access the internet via IE

IE says it's connected to the internet but can't reach google.com or microsoft.com

- I have added exceptions in the Firewall or turned it off completely
- I have tried to configure security via the wizard
- I have flushed dns with ipconfig
- I've removed any IP filter in Group Policy security options
- I've removed the IE Enhanced Security Configuration component

netmon capture when ie tried to reach google.ca
[image]

How can I get inbound/outbound HTTP / HTTP2 traffic to work for IE and ?

Comment: Try a non SSL webpage. It is possible your Internet Explorer can't handle new TLS.

Comment: What's serving your network connection? Make sure you don't have acls in place for testing the connection. Are you using the fresh IE without updating it?

Comment: the original IE 6 was updated to IE 8  ( I downloaded it on another machine). Updates don't work locally yet as internet doesn't work for IE or Activation

Comment: @Unfundednut yes! I tried http://www.zdnet.com/ and was able to pull back a rudimentary page - no CSS seemed to load

Comment: @Unfundednut - but it's odd - on a previous try of setting up WinSvr 2003 last week, I didn't have this issue

Comment: I was able to install the x86 version 46.0.1 of FireFox and can browse anything now. sheesh. maybe now I can Activate? I'll try

Comment: You can activate Windows Server offline easily enough.  Suggest the phone activation in a case like this

Answer (score 1):

Your server isn't having any trouble passing IP traffic to and from the Internet. The problem is strictly due to the fact you're trying to access web content through an unsupported and badly outdated version of Internet Explorer.

The best solution is to install another browser. Personally I'd use Firefox as I know it works on XP-era operating systems, despite their no longer being supported.

As for other Internet-based communication, such as activating software, that should work just fine (using a browser other than IE, if necessary).

Comment: Perhaps - as long as the server license 'Activate' feature doesn't work because of a setup / DNS / IP issue. I'm getting 403 errors when I examine the log. I was able to Activate last week on another Win Svr 2003 fresh install, so I'm not sure what went wrong this time.